# how to fix the following smarty bugs? (or php 5.3.8)

Tags: php, smarty

I have this bug

```
Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /var/www/html/includes/functions.php on line 1444
```

and this bug

```
Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /var/www/html/includes/templatelib/plugins/modifier.date_format.php on line 37
```

and this bug

```
Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /var/www/html/includes/functions.php on line 3538
```

I have read that the first is caused by the latest php version but the other 2 are smary bugs

I have seen on durpal forum, a similar error to the 1st one and the fix was to edit php.ini

and the fix was to add a timezone like `date.timezone = "America/New_York"` that doesn't work for me

**EDIT**

Ok so all of you agreed on 1 solution, i should edit my source code, should change anything in php.ini or not? because so far I've been trying to fix it from php.ini and didn't work

**Fixed it**

i had to change my vps timezone

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime
```

and do the same with php.ini, i also forgot to restart apache lol :D

Comment: Editing the *correct* php.ini file will mean that you don't need to edit every single php script you run. The fact that it hasn't been working most likely means that you've been editing the wrong file. Check your output from phpinfo() and make sure it's loading the correct file.

Comment: @Blair McMillan according to the php info file, i only have 1 php.ini file located in /etc/php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `date_default_timezone_set` at the beginning of your scripts, you should ensure that PHP is actually loading that configuration option properly. Check `phpinfo()`'s output.  Another potential gotcha: I don't know about your hosting setup but mine has multiple PHP ini files for different configurations and sometimes I edit the wrong one.  Conveniently phpinfo(); also tells you what .ini file(s) it's using so you can double-check with that.

That said, the `date_default_timezone_set` option other's have suggested is pretty much guaranteed to work.

Comment: I have seen the same issue with Joomla (not sure if they used smarty as their template engine), but setting a default value in php.ini fixed it. If you have access to php.ini, I would suggest that you set a default value corresponding to the timezone the server is in as @EPB has suggested.

Comment: Ah, I see, I hadn't even thought about that.  php.ini updates to PHP  as an Apache module would need a restart wouldn't it?  I'm so used to CGI that it hadn't even crossed my mind, sorry about that!  Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`

at the start of your PHP script? (Change 'Europe/London' to wherever you are, of course!)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Put this in the first line

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```